# converting a matrix of lists to a regular matrix

Tags: list, r, matrix

Take the following code:

```
foo <- list()
foo[[1]] <- list(a=1, b=2)
foo[[2]] <- list(a=11, b=22)
foo[[3]] <- list(a=111, b=222)
result <- do.call(rbind, foo)
result[,'a']
```

In this case, `result[,'a']` shows a list.  Is there a more elegant way such that `result` is a "regular" matrix of vectors?  I imagine there are manual ways of going about this, but I was wondering if there was an obvious step that I was missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do.call on lists is very elegant, and fast. In fact do.call(rbind, my.list) once saved my ass when I needed to combine a huge list. It was by far the fastest solution.

To solve your problem, maybe something like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, unlist))


> result.2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, unlist))
> result.2
       a   b
[1,]   1   2
[2,]  11  22
[3,] 111 222
> result.2[, 'a']
[1]   1  11 111
>
```

Comment: I wish `do.call` + `rbind` was fast.  Have you ever tried using it with 10,000 data frames in a list?!

Comment: @hadley: I seem to remember learning in a computation statistics class that this was the fastest way (after many other failed attempts) to bind lists. Maybe I'm remembering the wrong thing. What's faster?

Comment: You can manage about 4x faster if you carefully write it yourself.  `rbind.fill` in the next release of plyr will incorporate my latest best efforts.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting discussion; I discovered this comparison: http://www.biostat.wustl.edu/archives/html/s-news/2000-01/msg00169.html. My faith in do.call has been shattered! Thanks hadley.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is as follows (but am interested in alternatives):

```
new.result <- matrix(unlist(result), ncol=ncol(result), 
              dimnames=list(NULL, colnames(result)))
```